# symfony2: page always redirected to login page eventhough I logged-in

Tags: symfony-2.5

This is my security.yml file

```
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login
        anonymous: ~
        security: true

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        security: true
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            username_parameter: username
            password_parameter: password
            post_only: true
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: root

        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,methods: [GET] }
    - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,methods:[POST] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

After logged-in, always redirect to login page. Please help me. please refer below picture for my logged-in credential
[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context

Must use same context for both firewall as I used two firewall

```
 login:
    pattern:  ^/login
    anonymous: ~
    security: true
    context: my_context

main:
    pattern:    ^/
    anonymous: ~
    security: true
    ......
    context: my_context
```